# Assumptions in Integration for positive real values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

I want to evaluate the following integral in Mathematica.

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{a^{-t}-b^{-t}}{t} dt = \ln \left(\frac{\ln b}{\ln a} \right)$$

I try to enter this, but Mathematica can't figure it out.

`Integrate[  (a^(-t) - b^(-t))/t, {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, b > a}]`

It can figure out

`Integrate[  (3^(-t) - 5^(-t))/t, {t, 0, Infinity}]`

If someone could explain how to do the assumptions better I would appreciate it.

Comment: It gives me the answer in V13.0.1, with a condition, `a >= 1`.  Maybe add that to the assumptions in your version (or `a > 1`).

Comment: @MichaelE2: If `a==1`, then the integral diverges.

Comment: I suppose that's why I suggested `a > 1`, hmm?

Answer (score 2):

Plot the integrand to see, it explodes for 0<a<1 and a<b<1 as t goes to infinity, means integral does not converge.

Get desired result for 1<a and a<b

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[a^-t/t - b^-t/t, {a, 0, 2}, {b, a, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 100}], {{t, 1/1000}, 0, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Integrate[(a^(-t) - b^(-t))/t, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 1, b > 1, b > a}]

(*   -Log[Log[a]/Log[b]]   *)

Integrate[(a^(-t) - b^(-t))/t, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1, 0 < b < 1, b > a}]

(*   Integrate::idiv: Integral of a^-t/t-b^-t/t does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}. >>   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works in version 13 on Windows 10.

```
Integrate[(a^(-t) - b^(-t))/t, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[-Log[Log[a]/Log[b]], a >= 1 && b >= 1]`

If `(a<=1 && a>0)||(b<=1 && b >0)`, then the integral diverges.

Comment: One sees an inaccuracy in `ConditionalExpression[-Log[Log[a]/Log[b]], a >= 1 && b >= 1]` . It should be `ConditionalExpression[-Log[Log[a]/Log[b]], a > 1 && b > 1]` instead of.